# Maximo Anywhere Development Environment: Preview Version shows only Blank Screen

Tags: android, preview, maximo

I've installed Maximo Anywhere 7.6.2 and can install applications on Android devices and login properly. But when I try to do the same via the development environment (Preview Button on http://localhost:10080/worklightconsole), the simulator screen is shown blank instead of the login screen. 
Android 23.0.2 is installed with MaximoAnywhere.

Maximo is installed on port 9080. Following is the build.properties file content:

```
#Thu, 05 Jul 2018 11:31:07 +0500
## Application Build Properties File
##
## Update these settings specific to your environment
##

## Specifies the location of the build/deploy properties files
config.dir=${basedir}

## Specifies the location where you installed the Android SDK
android.sdk.home=C:/android-sdk

## Specifies the Android SDK target for building Android applications
Android_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME=android-23

## Specifies the BACKEND server the adapter will connect too
## these values get inserted into the OSLCGenericAdapter.xml
## and the authenticationConfig.xml
##
## If you want to have null or empty port or context comment out
## the property or set it to empty
## adapter.connection.port=
## adapter.connection.context=
## or
## ##adapter.connection.port=
## ##adapter.connection.context=
adapter.name=maximo
adapter.connection.protocol=http
adapter.connection.domain=ora.max.com
adapter.connection.port=9080
adapter.connection.context=maximo
#adapter.connection.user=
#adapter.connection.password=

## Specify folder or http URL where the platform zip file is present.
## for ex:
##platformzip.location=C:/Anywhere/AnywherePlatform
platformzip.location=C:/IBM/Anywhere/MaximoAnywhere/platform

## Specify the server url to where the apps and the adapter should be deployed
## (use ${local.IPAddress} for local server)
##
## TODO: if worklight.server.url is defined, this value overrides the individual
##       properties. The individual values should be derrived from worklight.server.url
##
worklight.server.url=http://ora.max.com:9080
worklight.server.protocol=http
worklight.server.domain=ora.max.com
worklight.server.port=9080
worklight.server.context=MaximoAnywhere
worklight.admin.server.context=wladmin
worklight.server.user=wasadmin
worklight.server.password=Admin123

## Specifies the URL to the Application Center where we will
## deploy the native applications. URL are specified in the
## format protocol://hostname.domain:port
##
## NOTE: If you are only running in Worklight Studio, Studio does not have a
##       appCenter. You can leave these properties unchanged.
appCenter.server.url=http://ora.max.com:9080
appCenter.server.context=applicationcenter
appCenterAdminID=wasadmin
appCenterAdminPass=Admin123

## Specify a list of environments to build. 'common' is implied.
## Possible values are android,iphone,windows8. Use comma to separate multiple
## values.
##
## NOTE: the iphone project is a Universal iOS application
##       and covers deployment to iphone and ipad environemnts.
worklight.envsToDeploy=android

## Specify a comma separated list of apps to build
## Possible values are AssetAudit, AssetDataManager, Inspection, IssuesReturns, PhysicalCount, ServiceRequest, Transfers, WorkApproval, WorkExecution
appsToBuild=AssetAudit, AssetDataManager, Inspection, IssuesReturns, PhysicalCount, ServiceRequest, Transfers, WorkApproval, WorkExecution

## set to 'true' to enable data encryption on the device
enableDataEncryption=false

##=========================================================
## Android Specific Build Toggles
##=========================================================

## Enable android application debugging feature
##
android.manifest.enable.debugging=false

##=========================================================
## iOS Specific Build Toggles
##=========================================================

# When building iOS applications for distribution (production),
# implicitly set the provisionprofile property to the name of the
# provision profile (located in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles)
# for Enterprise In-House Distribution builds.
#provisionprofile=8efae767-3d46-47a9-909c-2187d1ce133a

# application version number label
version.name=7.6.2

##=========================================================
## Begin INTERNAL build Properties
##=========================================================

## perform a debug build
##
##anywhere.debug=

production.build=true

# locations of visual studio tools
visualstudio.install.path=\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \

## visual studio version installed for use  eg: 12.0, 14.0
## Visual Studio 2013 - version 12.0
## Visual Studio 2015 - version 14.0
visualstudio.version.release=

# Platform targets to build the windows8 applications against.  Options available: x64 or x86
windows8.platform.target=

# The target configuration of the Appx.  Options available: Release or Debug
windows8.config.target=Release

## To support push notifications on android set these properties according to your setup documentation
android.pushSender.Key=
android.senderId=

# The type of build to be done. Possible values are build.target=mobilefirst, so just webcomponents will be built and deployed (war, wlapp, and adapter)
# and build.target=all, so complete build and deploy will be done (war, wlapp, adapter and native code, such as apk, ipa and appx).
build.target=all

## list of comma seperated properties that we do not want to update during upgrade process
ignore.properties.list=xcodeSDKVersion

## NOTIFICATION - iOS
## To support push notifications on ios set this property according to your setup documentation
ios.pushSender.password=
```

Comment: Could you open up your developer console in your browser, and put the output in this as supporting information?

Answer (score 0):

In MobileFirst Studio, make sure to go to the project explorer, right click on the application folder that you're interested in previewing and select run as > Run on Mobilefirst Development Server. That should deploy the application on the local development server.

The reason that you're able to connect with the real apps is because they're properly deployed to the real Mobilefirst Server. For development purposes, the apps needs to be deployed to the local Mobilefirst Server that you should be able to find in Mobilefirst Studio in the 'Servers' tab. Also make sure that this is started before attempting to deploy any apps. To start the local Mobilefirst Server, right click on it and select 'Start'. When successfully started, it should say '[Started, Synchronized]' to the right of the name of the server.